# Was Hallmund's daughter a troll or half-troll?

Tags: norse

Was Hallmund?  In Grettir's Saga, he is depicted as extraordinary, and she lives in a remote cave and is described as:

> "a woman, great of growth, but shapely withal"
>   <sub>[Source: [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2003.02.0005%3Achapter%3D62)]</sub>

I ask because Grettir's Saga has a fair amount of supernatural components, which I recall as somewhat distinct from the overall body of Icelandic sagas.  Hallmund himself is said to be of remarkable size, and describes his own interaction with the supernatural in his death poem:

> "With the giant's kin 
>   Have I oft raised din 
>   To the rock folk 
>   Have I dealt out stroke; 
>   Ill things could tell 
>   That I smote full well; 
>   The half-trolls know 
>   My baneful blow. 
>   "Small gain in me 
>   Did the elf-folk see, 
>   Or the evil wights 
>   Who ride anights."

---

*PS: I seem to recall a short verse in the Fox/Palsson translation where Grettir calls himself "punisher of the elves", but I couldn't located it in the Perseus text.  Is my memory incorrect?  Perhaps I am conflating it with Hallmund's verse: "small gain in me did the elf-folk see"?*